# Get image in javascript based on variable value

Tags: javascript, html

Supposing I save my image files accordingly, saved in the same folder as the html file, e.g. Card_4_13.jpg, generally Card_"Suit"_"Value".jpg

Is there a way I can use the variables S (1-4) and V (1-13) in order to get the card Card_"S"_"V".jpg?

I intend to avoid creating 4*13 "if" functions to finish this job. For I am yet a beginner, I am curious whether or not this is possible. Any reply is much appreciated

Comment: It's probably worth your time to step back from your current task and work through some basic JavaScript tutorials and/or a good beginner's book and/or course. The task above is very basic. Basic questions are not necessary bad questions or off-topic, but you'll learn more, and more quickly, with a structured tutorial/book/course. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use nested loops and either *string concatenation* (adding strings together):

```js
for (var suit = 1; suit <= 4; ++suit) {
  for (var card = 1; card <= 13; ++card) {
    var name = "Card_" + suit + "_" + card + ".jpg";
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...or a ES2015+ *template literal*:

```js
for (let suit = 1; suit <= 4; ++suit) {
  for (let card = 1; card <= 13; ++card) {
    const name = `Card_${suit}_${card}.jpg`;
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```